# Have to type "exit" on GRUB command line at boot to access normal GRUB menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

OS: Windows 10

Drives:

1. 128GB SSD (where efi for windows10 located) (/dev/nvme0n1p1, /dev/nvme0n1p2 and so on)
2. 1TB HHD (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2 and so on)

While I was installing Ubuntu 20.04, I partitioned my root, home and swap areas in the HHD. Since I read some tutorials saying Ubuntu is smart enough to detect bootable Operating Systems, I just installed the boot loader in the SSD drive. After installation everything worked! I successfully booted into the GRUB menu and was able to choose Ubuntu or Windows.

When I boot into Ubuntu, and then reboot the laptop, I get the grub command line ("minimal bash-like line editing...") instead of the grub menu. This is actually not a big problem for me because when I type `exit` I am able to get back to my grub menu again and boot normally.

I've searched but it seems nobody has this specific question (most scenarios I saw involved not being able to boot into any OS normally, which is not my case). I also tried some other tutorials but it doesn't seem to work :(

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: We had an issue like that and the solution was to change the boot order in the firmware settings (BIOS/UEFI). Have you had a look there? If it shows GRUB or something that refers to the SSD where GRUB is installed, try putting that first (and/or try all the options for reordering the list and see if any of them work...)

Answer (score 0):

Check your boot setup with `grub-customizer`. Maybe grub console is a default boot entry.

Comment: The default entry is : (first entry). Otherwise the other options are :ubuntu, advanced option(ubuntu recovery and so on), Windows Boot Manager and UEFI Firmware Setting. I don't think grub console is the default one.