# How to boot into ubuntu without having to type exit wice?

Tags: boot, 20.04, grub-efi

Apologies in advance and I'm not an expert and I've got access to a machine previously configured without a lot of context.

I know it used to have windows but unsure it currently still has it.
I know it us running Ubuntu 20.04 but to boot into it I need to type `exit` twice in `grub`.

I'm not Ubuntu expert, so started by looking at existing relevant answers.
Here's what I've tried so far:

1. based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336051/have-to-type-exit-on-grub-command-line-at-boot-to-access-normal-grub-menu) I've installed and `grub-customizer` and moved `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic` to the top (as this is what I see after running `uname -a`). (Bellow there's another similar entry: `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-53-generic`. Maybe there are two Ubuntu installs ?). I've saved/rebooted: didn't seem to make a difference/still need to type in `exit` twice after rebooting.
2. based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842141/booting-into-ubuntu-without-grub) I've tried commenting out `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE`, ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted: still no joy.

In grub this is what I can see:

[image: ubuntu grub menu]

I don't fully undertsand why I need to type `exit` in `grub` , but my hunch is maybe there are two version of Ubuntu installed and the current config doesn't explicity boot into one ?
(It doesn't list the typical OS select screen though).

How can configure `grub` so the machine boots into Ubuntu 20.04 on it's own, without me typing `exit` twice ?

Comment: Grub Customizer replaces grub's scripts with its own proxy scripts. Are you booting in BIOS or UEFI boot mode? And then if newer system with both modes available, is boot mode in UEFI/BIOS settings match boot mode of Ubuntu install? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Looks like BIOS: `ls: cannot access '/sys/firmware/efi': No such file or directory`, `test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios` outputs `bios`. In BIOS settings I see `ubuntu` as the first boot option. This is the [BootInfo summary report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/JzwbwWrPcb/). I've installed `boot-repair` as well, but haven't ran it yet. Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: You have UEFI system. You have BIOS grub in MBR and UEFI grub in ESP on MBR partitioned drive. Since only Ubuntu would be better to have been gpt whether UEFI or BIOS as only time to use MBR(msdos) is with Windows in BIOS boot mode. It looks like grub in ESP for UEFI boot is looking for a non-existent partiiton. But you have mount of ESP in fstab for UEFI boot. So is it trying to boot in UEFI mode, fails and then boots in BIOS mode?  Because report was from BIOS, it did not show efibootmgr -v output which shows UEFI/BIOS boot entrees.